# Android class MediaPlayer's attachAuxEffect does not work

Tags: android

I write the following code and apply them after the playback starts(mp.start()).

```
  PresetReverb pr = new PresetReverb(100, 0);
  mp.attachAuxEffect(pr.getId());
  mp.setAuxEffectSendLevel((float)0.7);
```

And i could not hear any difference from when I don't apply the above code. Why? How to use this method?
I already add the permission MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS by the way.

Comment: same issue with me, have you found any solution?

Comment: I also don't have any results when trying to get PresetReverb enabled. Notice that you don't call  `pr.setPreset()`. However, this didn't change anything for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with following code:

```
PresetReverb pr = new PresetReverb(0, 0);
pr.setPreset(PRESET_LARGEHALL);
pr.setEnabled(true);
mp.attachAuxEffect(pr.getId());
mp.setAuxEffectSendLevel((float)0.7);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it like

```
PresetReverb mReverb = new PresetReverb(0,mMediaPlayer.getAudioSessionId());//<<<<<<<<<<<<<
mReverb.setPreset(PresetReverb.PRESET_SMALLROOM);
mReverb.setEnabled(true);
mMediaPlayer.setAuxEffectSendLevel(1.0f);
```

> And no need to call mMediaPlayer.attachAuxEffect(mReverb.getId()) . It is already set. And global audio Session id 0 is deprecated..